# How to use ViewModel to update TextView after typing data in several EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have 3 questions each displayed in a fragment. After each question there is a fragment that has a TextView which has the answer that was typed in in the EditText of the previous questions fragment. I managed to achieve that the typed in data of the first question is displayed in the second fragment but when I go to the next question, in the EditText there is the data of the first question. How do I use the code shown here so the input of every question is only shown in the next fragment? (fragments: question 1 --> answer 1 --> question 2 --> answer 2 --> question 3 --> answer 3)

Here is the code of the first two fragments and the ModelView:

First Question Fragment:

```
public class FragmentQuestion1 extends Fragment {

private Button btnNavFrag1;
private EditText mEditTextQuestion1;
private SharedViewModel viewModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_1, container, false);

    btnNavFrag1 = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_question1);

    mEditTextQuestion1 = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_question_1);

    btnNavFrag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            viewModel.getAnswer(1);

            ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(2);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String answer) {
            viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);
            mEditTextQuestion1.setText(answer);
        }
    });
}
```

First Answer overview Fragment:

```
public class FragmentAnswer1 extends Fragment {

private View btnNavFragAns1;
private TextView tv_answer1;
private SharedViewModel viewModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_answer_1, container, false);

    btnNavFragAns1 = view.findViewById(R.id.next_question_1);

    tv_answer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_player_1_text_view);

    btnNavFragAns1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ((GameActivity)getActivity()).setViewPager(3);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String answer) {
            viewModel.setAnswer(1, answer);
            tv_answer1.setText(answer);
        }
    });
}
```

Shared View Model:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {


public HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>> answers = new HashMap<Integer, MutableLiveData<String>>(){{
    put(1, new MutableLiveData<String>());
    put(2, new MutableLiveData<String>());
    put(3, new MutableLiveData<String>());
}};



public MutableLiveData<String> getAnswer(int questionId) {
    return answers.get(questionId);
}

public void setAnswer(int questionId, String answer) {
    if (answers.get(questionId) != null) {
        answers.get(questionId).setValue(answer);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a shared `ViewModel` which stores a list of `LiveData` for answers and maybe a list for questions.

Here is an updated version of your `SharedViewModel`:

```java
public class ContestViewModel extends ViewModel {

private HashMap<Int,LiveData<String>> answers = new HashMap<>();

public LiveData<String> getAnswer(int questionId) {
    return answers.get(questionId);
}
public void setAnswer(int questionId, String answer) {
    // TODO make sure that answers.get is not null
    answers.get(questionId).setValue(answer);
  }
}
```

Now, in each fragment just call `viewModel.getAnswer(id)`. So, each of them has a separated livedata for its question/answer.

Comment: So the questionID is the name of the EditText of each question?

Comment: I actually don't know how to implement this code. When I do the setValue gets an error

Comment: Now question id is the tag for each of your fragment, so in answer1 you should use `1` in answer2 you should use `2` and so on.

Comment: You should also call setAnswer when ever your edit text change and also observe on getAnswer to show your text

Comment: When I do this now I get a NullPointerException in this line:  viewModel.getAnswer(1).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>()

Comment: @DanielSpatz I'd written a comment in the code, it's not going to work it just give you an idea how to do it. In the `ContestViewModel`'s constructor, you should initialize your map

Comment: Ok since I am relatively new to programming I don't know how to do these things right now but I will look it up, thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Hello @Saeed Masoumi, I kinda managed to do some changes to the code but the TextView still does not getting updated. I would really appreciate it if you can have a look and maybe tell me what I am missing